# Mocha before and after hooks not executing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to run a simple test on my local cassandra database to check if the select statement returns the correct no of records from the table. However, the code placed between the before and after blocks are not getting called. As a result my test simply fails.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var async = require('async');

//Connect to the cassandra cluster, assuming that the keyspace & columnspace already exists
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace: 'demo'}); 
describe('Cassandra is up and running', function() {
    before(function() {
        //Check if the connection got established successfuly 
        client.connect(function(err) {
            if(err){
                console.log("Oops, something went wrong : " + err);
            }
            console.log('I al here 1');
        });

        //Insert a few data to column space
        var queries = [
        {
        query: 'INSERT INTO users(key, name, emails) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        params: ['mick-jagger1', 'Sir Mick Jagger 1', 'mick1@company.com']
        },
        {
        query: 'INSERT INTO users(key, name, emails) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        params: ['mick-jagger2', 'Sir Mick Jagger 2', 'mick2@company.com']
        },
        {
        query: 'INSERT INTO users(key, name, emails) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        params: ['mick-jagger3', 'Sir Mick Jagger 3', 'mick3@company.com']
        },
        {
        query: 'INSERT INTO users(key, name, emails) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        params: ['mick-jagger4', 'Sir Mick Jagger 4', 'mick4@company.com']
        }
        ];

        client.batch(queries, { prepare: true }, function(err) {
            if(err){
                console.log("Oops, something went wrong : " + err);
            }
            console.log('Sample data inserted into column space');
        });
    })

    it('should return 4 when four rows of data are inserted into demo table', function() {
        var count = 0;
        client.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users', function(err, result) {
            count = result.rows[0];
        });
        assert.equal(4, count);
        console.log("I am here : " + count);
    })

    after(function() {
        client.execute('TRUNCATE users', function(err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.log("Oops, something went wrong : " + err);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test is performing asynchronous operations. You need to use a callback to tell mocha when your it/before/after functions have finished. For example:

```
before(function(done) {
    // ...
    client.batch(queries, {
        prepare: true
    }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Oops, something went wrong : " + err);
            }
            console.log('Sample data inserted into column space');
            done();
        });
});
```

and:

```
it('should return 4 when four rows of data are inserted into demo table', function(done) {
    var count = 0;
    client.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users', function(err, result) {
        count = result.rows[0];
        assert.equal(4, count);
        console.log("I am here : " + count);
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `client.batch` should be called inside the `client.connect` callback, since `client.connect` is asynchronous too. Or you could end up in a situation where you'll execute your queries before it finishes connecting.

Comment: Thank you for shedding some light on callbacks. Now I am able to execute the before, it and after parts of my tests.

Answer (score 0):

**ES6 update**

You can now use async/await pattern for this case:

```js
before(async () => {
        // ...
        try {
         await client.batch(queries, {
            prepare: true
          });
        } catch (err) {
        if(err) {
         console.log("Oops, something went wrong : " + err)
          }
        console.log('Sample data inserted into column space');
        }
    });

it('should return 4 when four rows of data are inserted into demo table', async () => {
      var count = 0;
      await client.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users', (err, result) => { 
       count = result.rows[0];
        assert.equal(4, count);
        console.log("I am here : " + count);
      });
    });
```